# Set point of projection

Tags: actionscript-3, math, game-physics, trigonometry

Im working on game project. I have a scenario, in which the stage will contain circles in random position. When I press the up arrow key I want the circles to move in 3 dimensional axis from the center.

The width of the stage is 550 and the height of the stage is 300.

What I want is,

- the circles that are positioned equal to the center of the stage(550/2) should travel in 90 degree.
  [image: In the above image the circle falls within the center so I want it to travel in 90 degree]
- the circles that are positioned lesser than the center of the stage(550/2) should travel in angle lesser than 90 degree, with a difference from the center.
  [image: In the image the circles should travel in angle lesser than 90 degree and the angle should vary based on the difference from the center]
  **In the image the circles should travel in angle  lesser than 90 degree and the angle should increase based on the difference from the center**
- the circles that are positioned greater than the center of the stage(550/2) should travel in angle greater than 90 degree,  with a difference from the center.
  [image: In the image the circles should travel in angle greater than 90 degree and the angle should vary based on the difference from the center]
  **In the image the circles should travel in angle  greater than 90 degree and the angle should increase based on the difference from the center**

what I have done is

```
var stage_width = 550;
var stage_height = 300;
var stage_center = stage_width/2;
var speed = 5;
var default_angle = 90 * Math.PI/180;

for(i = 0; i< 1; i++)
{
     var circle = _root.attachMovie('circle','circle_mc_'+i,_root.getNextHighestDepth());
    circle._x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 551);
    circle._y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 301);
    circle.obj_x = circle._x;
    circle.onEnterFrame = function()
    {
        Key.addListener(this);
        this.onKeyDown = function()
        {
            if(Key.UP  == Key.getCode())
            {
                if(this._x == stage_center)
                {
                    this._x = this._x + Math.cos(default_angle) * speed;
                    this._y = this._y + Math.sin(default_angle) * speed;
                }   
                else if(this._x > stage_center)
                {
                    var diff = this.obj_x - stage_center;
                    // I need a solution here to find the angle
                    var angle = ((90 - diff)<0)?-(90 - diff): 90 - diff;
                    var rad = (angle) * Math.PI/180;
                    this._x = this._x + Math.cos(rad) * speed;
                    this._y = this._y + Math.sin(rad) * speed;
                }
                else if(this._x < stage_center)
                {
                    var diff = stage_center - this.obj_x;
                    // I need a solution here to find the angle
                    var angle = ((90 + diff)>180)? 180: 90 + diff;
                    var rad = (angle) * Math.PI/180;
                    this._x = this._x + Math.cos(rad) * speed;
                    this._y = this._y + Math.sin(rad) * speed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know how to find the angle greater or lesser than 90 degree based on the difference from the center and the assigned position. Kindly provide me  solution to find the angle

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can is to imagine a half circle with radius 550/2 around your centre. If you do that, then the X coordinate of your ball becomes the cosine of the angle you need, and the Y coordinate becomes the sine.

Now, to rotate a vector by some angle, let's say A, you just need to left multiply it by:

```
|cos(A) -sin(A)|
|sin(A)  cos(A)|
```

But since cos(A) = X and sin(A) = Y:

```
|X -Y|
|Y  X|
```

(I expect this to work if the Y=0 is at the top of the screen.)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix